# Convert number into double

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I would like to convert the following number into a double.

```
Number mMax_Distance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
```

I am using Parse, and in it I have a column known as Maximum_distance and that is classified as a number.

I need to convert it into a number because I would like to use in the following line:

```
query.whereWithinKilometers("location", point, mMax_Distance);
```

where mMax_Distance has to be a double

The other way to resolve it is to store it directly as a double instead of a number. However, it was classified using a seekbar value, where users determines their maximum distance through a seekbar, and I believe seekbar only stores numbers.

```
currentUser.put("Maximum_Distance", seekBarDistance.getProgress());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you require clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Number.doubleValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue())